# Git - URL does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git

I just started using Git and now I'm experiencing a problem.

I have a production server and a local development repository. All files on my local master branch should be on the production server. So after every change on the master branch I push to the production server. First time, all files should be pushed obviously.

I created a repository on the server and got this message `Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/my_really_cool_project/.git/`. Then I added the remote on the local machine, but whenever pushing it logs `'181.910.139.164/var/wwww/my_really_cool_project/.git' does not appear to be a git repository`. I probably made a mistake in the URL but I have no idea what the problem is. Connection via SSH goes via port 4938.

Is anyone able to tell me what the problem is here? I'm really stuck on this.

This is the output of `git remote show origin`:

```
fatal: '181.910.139.164/var/wwww/my_really_cool_project/.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: It appears you're missing a colon (`:`) between the host part and the path part in the URL. Please include the output of `git remote show origin` in your question to verify this and I'll be happy to provide an answer.

Comment: I added it. It is the some output as `git push origin master`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gertvdijk's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405377/git-url-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository?noredirect=1#comment520509_405377) was right.

Instead of `181.910.139.164/var/wwww/my_really_cool_project/.git` I should have used `181.910.139.164:/var/wwww/my_really_cool_project/.git`. As you can see I added a colon.