# fatal: does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: server, repository, git

I set up a empty git repo on my production server with

```
git init --bare
```

From my local machine i added the repo as a remote:

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@example.com/~/git/example.com
```

If i issue following command

```
git remote show origin
```

I get an error message saying:

```
fatal: '~/git/example.com' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried the colon as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405377/git-url-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository), but it didn't help.

Comment: With your 'remote add origin' command, try to use the absolute path to the repository and not the one relating to home (the ~ shows this). Also try to just ssh to the remote machine to confirm that it is working.

Comment: I can ssh to my machine without any problems. Also using the absolute path gives me the same results as before.

Answer (score 6):

With SSH URLs, relative paths start from your home directory, and it doesn't understand shell shortcuts like `~`. So do:

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@example.com/git/example.com
```

if you want to use absolute paths, like `/home/mario/git/example.com`, use an extra leading slash:

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@example.com//home/mario/git/example.com
```

Comment: i tried both of your suggestions, but i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

This means that the remote server does not have a repo at ~/git/example.com I suspect you have the address wrong. Most git addresses will be something like git@server.com:project.git. Most do not have a path or a reference to ~

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer to my own problem...

I am using the URL conventions used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134428/4779750) post

The Domain i was using was just defined in my local hosts file. Which seems to work with everything else, accept for git.

I then replaced the example.com part with the actual Server IP and got it working.